# Can I keep the "public key" a secret

Tags: security, encryption, rsa, public-key

I would like to use an asymmetric encryption process without making the "public" key really public.

My world contains 3 actors : A, B, C and a public message bank.

I want A to be the only one able to encrypt (and decrypt) short messages in the bank (for example AES keys), and I want A to be able to later chose who gains access to the encrypted data in the bank without the need to re-encrypt or add messages to the bank.

It would go like this:

A generates a key pair with RSA : (p1,p2), p1 being the "private" key (used here only for encryption) and p2 being the "public" key (used here only for decryption)

A encrypts the messages with p1 and stores them in the public bank : A, B and C can access the stored encrypted messages. For now, only A can decrypt the messages.

Later, A wants B (and only B) to be able to read the messages (but not to write more messages in his name in the bank), so he gives p2 to B in some secure way.

Is it a correct use of the RSA algorithm ? Does RSA ensure that B and C will not be able to read M without the "public" key p2?
Why does the vocabulary around asymmetric encryption seem to deter me from doing so? Is there a better way to achieve the same functionality ?

Any advice would be much appreciated

EDIT :
I know that I'm not using the RSA protocol in the usual way (public key encryption/ private key decryption), but the math behind it (as I understand it) should allow working the other way around.

Comment: _""private" key (used here only for encryption) and p2 being the "public" key (used here only for decryption)"_ - you got these mixed up. Public key can encrypt but not decrypt. Private key can decrypt.

Comment: private key encryption is used widely for verification, and the public RSA key seems to be used here as an example (https://www.novixys.com/blog/using-aes-rsa-file-encryption-decryption-java/ ) (step 10) to decrypt a message (an AES key).